# .net 4.5 web application redirects to ReturnUrl=%2f

Tags: .net-4.5, iis-express, asp.net-4.5, vs-web-application-project, .net-4.5.2

I created a web application targeting 4.5.2 framework and using IIS8.
The starting page should be Default.aspx, It used to work OK on framework 3.5 but on framework 4.5.2 it redirects me to Domain\Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f web page even after I've logged in correctly.

I know it can be fixed by adding some code in Global.Application_BeginRequest in Global.asax but I really want to know the real cause of this behaviour and which dll added by .net v4.5 makes this redirect to the root path ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I was trying to fix this loop and it looks it was an authentification issue with .net framework 4.5
you just need to remove the authorize section of the login page in your web config file :

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".config" type="System.Web.Compilation.IgnoreFileBuildProvider"/>
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Default.aspx" defaultUrl="yourlink" timeout="60" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication> 
<!--<authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
 </authorization>-->
```

Also in  section add this key  to solve Unobtrusive Validation Mode in ASP.NET 4.5

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```

and the loop to root path is gone!